Would the sum of two perfectly monochromatic waves be coherent?
I am struggling to understand classical, first order degree of coherence.
It is often said that coherent light must be monochromatic, i.e. that only a perfectly sinusoidal wave can be considered coherent. In reality it is not possible to generate such a wave, and any wave would instead be composed of a narrow band of frequencies following some distribution. This distribution of frequencies then determines the ability of the wave to self-interfere across displacements, or remain coherent. One interpretation of this might be that the subwaves begin in-sync, and become out-of-sync after enough time due to their slightly different periods, never to meaningfully sync back up because the distribution of subfrequencies is continuous.
Thus light from a single point source:
$$
E(t) = e^{i \omega_1 t}
$$
is coherent. This manifests in that E(t) can be displaced from itself across arbitrary time/distance and still cyclically interfere with itself. We can see it mathematically by computing the first order correlation function:
$$
\gamma(\tau) \equiv \frac{\langle E^*(t)E(t+\tau)\rangle}{\langle | E(t)|^2\rangle}
$$
where $\tau$ is some time delay. It is straightforward to show that for the point source, this becomes:
$$
\gamma(\tau) = e^{-i\omega_1 \tau}
$$
This correlation does not diminish with increasing $\tau$, e.g. for collision-broadened light about a central frequency $\omega_1$ the correlation is instead:
$$
\gamma(\tau) = e^{\frac{-\tau}{\tau_C}}e^{-i\omega_1 \tau}
$$
where $\tau_C$ is a constant, the "coherence time".
But I don't understand why then a wave composed of two perfect frequencies would not be considered coherent. If the wave is instead:
$$
E(t) = e^{i \omega_1 t} + e^{i \omega_2 t}
$$
Doesn't this wave also interfere with itself cyclically over arbitrary displacements? Calculating the correlation I get:
$$
\gamma(\tau) = \frac{e^{i\omega_1 \tau}+e^{i\omega_2 \tau}}{2}
$$
Which similarly doesn't diminish with increasing $\tau$. So it cyclically correlates with itself regardless of displacement. Which it clearly does, the wave is still a periodic function just with a different waveform.
Couldn't we even select any waveform that is periodic on an appreciable scale and consider it coherent? For example, replacing the perfect sinusoid with a sawtooth pattern of same period. Such a wave would also cyclically constructively/deconstructively interfere with itself across arbitrary displacements, no?
It feels like coherence is a matter of the periodicity (or lack thereof) of the wave. For waves which aren't truly periodic, coherence then feels like a measure of the rate at which the wave deforms from its original local waveform. Is this all just moot because in reality there are no perfect sources?

In the frequency domain, the bandwidth $\Delta f$ of a spectral feature is approximately related to the coherence time $\tau$ by $\tau \approx 1/\Delta f$ (waving my hands, ignoring factors of $2\pi$).
So a delta function in frequency is coherent for an infinite time. A realistic source would have some spread in frequencies about a peak instead of being a perfect delta function, and so would have a finite coherence time.
I would classify your case as having two perfectly coherent sources at different frequencies. Of course, realistically, both should have some width, and so won't be perfectly coherent.
If the widths are small compared to their separation, then they will behave as basically two distinct sources superposed with each other. In the opposite extreme limit, their bandwidths will overlap, then the two sources will interfere and the combined bandwidth will further wash out any coherence.

A radar/comm engineer would consider two ideal sinusoidal waves, say $s(t)=Ae^{\mathfrak j\omega_0 t}$ and $x(t)=Be^{\mathfrak j\omega_x t}$, coherent. For example, let $s(t)$ denote the transmitted signal (wave) and $x(t)$ the reflected wave whose carrier frequency is Doppler shifted in amount of $\Delta \omega_x = \omega_x - \omega_0$ because the reflector is moving relative to the transmitter.
Of course, $\omega_0$ is known, it is determined by the transmitter but $\omega_x$ is unknown unless the reflector's velocity is given. In fact, the relative radial (line of sight) velocity is directly proportional to $\Delta \omega$ which we wish to measure.
The receiver measures the frequency shift by correlating the received signal $x(t)$ with a series of locally generated and frequency shifted replicas of $\omega_n$, that is with $r_n(t)=R e^{\mathfrak j\omega_n t}$ where $\omega_n = \omega_0+n\delta \omega;\, n=0,\pm1,\pm2,...$ and $\delta \omega$ is a sufficiently narrow frequency error that the radar can tolerate. The measurement then is the correlation $$\langle x(t)\bar r_n(t)\rangle \propto  RB \frac{\sin\tfrac{\Delta \omega - n\delta \omega}{2}}{\tfrac{\Delta \omega-n\delta \omega}{2}},$$
and then selecting the estimate $\hat n\delta \omega$ for $\Delta \omega$ that $\hat n=n$ for which $|\Delta \omega-n\delta \omega|$ is the smallest, i.e., closest to zero.
Moreover, one can accumulate these complex number correlations before decision from several transmitted and reflected pulses coherently in the same frequency bin $n\delta \omega$ as long as the target moves with a constant line of sight velocity. One can even handle maneuvering, accelerating motion by coherently accumulating in a linear sequence of neighboring frequency bins, etc.
All this can be done because of the known variation of the reflected phase. Of course, here "known phase" is to be understood as to make various statistical estimates on the actual reflected phase response and then select, say, the maximum likelihood estimate. But the essential ingredient that allows these operations is the temporal coherence, in other words, relative temporal predictability, of the two waves.
